# How do i return bit value from a select statement when a column value in the statement is null

Tags: sql-server, string, null, bit

In a select query one of the columns is a nullable varchar column. How does one return a `1` or `0` as a bit value if that specific column is NULL?

I have tried doing something like this

```
select
    isnull(nullif(isnull(JavascriptCode, 0),JavascriptCode), 1) as HasJavaScriptCode
from code
```

but that seems to return a string value so i cant use in my code.

Comment: if it's null you want a 0 or a 1?

Comment: if it's null, i want a 0 and if it contains a value i want a 1 @Lamak

Comment: `CASE WHEN JavascriptCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN JavascriptCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As bit) As HasJavaScriptCode
FROM code
```

Since 2012 version (which is currently the oldest supported version) SQL Server supports [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - which can be used instead of simply `case` expressions to create a more concise code:

```
SELECT CAST(IIF(JavascriptCode IS NULL, 0,1) As bit) As HasJavaScriptCode
FROM code
```

Comment: This does NOT return bit values! In fact it's an integer which is returned. If you are concerned about type safety, you definitely need to cast. (As in Giorgi Nakeuris anwer.)

Comment: @FastJack correct. I've edited my answer and also added an `IIF` version.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE` expression with `CAST`:

```
select
    case when JavascriptCode is null 
         then cast(0 as bit) 
         else cast(1 as bit) end as HasJavaScriptCode
from code
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everyone is agreeing that you should use a case statement.  I would point out that you should clearly define if the column might contain an empty string and what that might mean in terms of returning 1 or 0.  One solution might look like this:

```
select
  cast(
    case when JavascriptCode is null or len(JavascriptCode) = 0
      then 0
      else 1
    end
    as bit
  ) as HasJavascriptCode
from code
```

Just another variation on the many ways you can write this type of statement.  This one simply wraps the case statement in a cast to prevent one of the cases from not being a bit.  I admit that it isn't as pleasing on the eyes.

Comment: There is no need for the extra steps here. An empty string will implicitly cast to bit as a 0. select CAST('' as bit)

Comment: That is an interesting fact, but since we're using a case statement to return either 0 or 1, I'm not sure I see where the casting of empty string to a bit comes into play.